c# Skiasharp finding SKEncodedImageFormat from image read from a Stream
I'm hoping someone can help.
I have an image as a byte array read from a stream.
I don't know the format of the image, which could be one of many.
I want to use the c# SkiaSharp nuget library to read this byte[], add to it then return it as a stream keeping the same format.
I believe I need to find the format so I can get it when I create the returning stream.
Is that correct?
How do I find the image format from either an SKImage or SKBitmap?
    public byte[] ManipulateImage(byte[] bytes)
    {
        using var bytesStream = new MemoryStream(bytes);
        // Didn't know to use SKImage or SKBitmap. And do I need the ToRasterImage bit?
        using var skImage = SKImage.FromEncodedData(bytesStream).ToRasterImage();

        using var surface = SKSurface.Create(skImage.Info);
        var canvas = surface.Canvas;
        canvas.DrawImage(skImage, 0, 0);

        // Looked at this but doesn't help
        SKData d = skImage.EncodedData;

        // Want to overlay another image here and convert to stream to return
        // .......
        
        // Here I've hardcoded SKEncodedImageFormat.Png but want to get it from the original image byte array?
        using var skData = skImage.Encode(SKEncodedImageFormat.Png, 100);
        skData.AsStream().Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
        skData.AsStream().CopyTo(outputMemoryStream);

        return outputMemoryStream.ToArray();
    }

